# Need help Speeding up this Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a program which scans the users that are online on a server and for each user found inserts a new row in a table. This scan occurs once every 5 minutes and the data is used to draw a user-activity graph on a website.

Here is the structure of my table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                   stats_table                       |
-------------------------------------------------------
| id, bigint(20) unsigned not null PRI auto_increment |
| scan_id, bigint(20) unsigned not null               |
| username, varchar(32) null                          |
| time_scanned, timestamp not null def=curr_timestamp |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the **aggregate** number of users found since midnight, **for each scan**.

I have managed to get this, but the query takes over 15 seconds to finish:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.scan_id, t1.username FROM
   stats_table INNER JOIN stats_table t1 ON
   t.scan_id >= t1.scan_id WHERE
   t1.time_scanned > CONCAT(DATE(t.time_scanned), ' 00:00:00') AND
   t1.time_scanned > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND
   t1.time_scanned <= NOW()
) s GROUP BY s.scan_id
```

so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to get this result?

Here is a visual representation on my graph. Blue represents currently online users, and red the aggregate number of users seen so far today:

[image]

To clarify, at 17:00 hours 2 users disconnected and then 15 minutes later 2 new users connected to the server for the first time since midnight. You can see how the red line goes from 7 up to 9 to represent this. Similarly, a new user also connected for the first time today at 23:00.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: @AndyLester Sure thing! I have edited my OP. Let me know if this info is sufficient. Cheers.

Comment: @Chris: You've got the table definition, but what about the index definitions?

Comment: @AndyLester Maybe I'm clueless, but the only index here is the Primary Key? Perhaps you are referring to something else?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the only index you have is the primary key, and that's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not see and index definition I'll assume it is not there.
What you need to do is add an index on the query you are running:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Note this will most likely cause a slower insert/update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a `PRIMARY KEY`. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: The primary key is always indexed but you are also doing a subquery selection with

SELECT DISTINCT t.scan_id, t1.username


so you need to add to all of these

Comment: Oh I see. So just to clarify: All I need to do is to add an index to the `scan_id` column and another one to the `username` column, right?

Like this: `CREATE INDEX scan_id ON stats_table (scan_id);` ?

Comment: CREATE   INDEX stats_table_in_sel_index 
    ON stats_table (scan_id, username);

This is the most basic part.
Now you need to probably add sections of the where clause. Concatenation and subs but this should give noticeable result.

Comment: @Chris: Please read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ as a tutorial about indexing so that you understand *why* you are indexing the columns that you are indexing.